# How to center the text under the icon

Tags: html, css, text, center

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

I am just wanting the "Chat" to be centered under the icon and still be responsive.  Here is my current html and css for it:

```
'<div class="container w3-margin-bottom">' +
    '<img class="w3-margin-bottom w3-margin-top container" width="96px" height="96px" src="/CustomSpace/EndUserHome/Icons/UserHelp_96px.svg">' +
    '<div class="w3-cell w3-xlarge w3-text-blue"><div class="text-styling-bold" style="overflow-wrap: anywhere">Chat</div></div>' +
'</div>' +

.container{
   display: flex;
   flex: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

(I understand the w3.css is not a professional library, but it was what was being used before I got here)

Comment: Your example is confusing due to the fact that the HTML appears to be ripped from some JavaScript, but care was not taken to remove the JavaScript parts. You can use Stack Snippets to make it runnable (icon looks like `<>` in a page on the editor toolbar). I expect it has something to do with `flex: row` which is invalid. It should be `flex-flow: row` and could be combined with the next line to produce `flex-flow: row wrap`. Although I think you'd rather appreciate the look of `flex-flow: column wrap` more...

Comment: add justify-content:center

Comment: Sorry, I am new to posting here, the html is from a JavaScript file, I will be sure to remove all of those parts next time.  Thank you for your explanation, I will use the Stack Snippets next time.  And thank you for your answer, that did fix my problem.